# Beta Reduction steps on Y combinator

Tags: lambda-calculus, y-combinator

I am new to studying Lambda Calculus as part of my CompSci degree. In the course material (this is not a graded assignment no worries!) the following beta reduction came up:

. → .() → .(()) → .((()))

I am slightly confused as I didn't think we could just add something in a beta reduction step. Anyone can explain this a little to me or give me hints on why this behaves that way? Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What is the definition of `W` here?